# Connecting to SQL Server very slow

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

I have a standard php app that uses SQL Server as the back-end database. There is a serious delay in response for each page I access. This is my development server, so its not an issue with the live setup, but it is really annoying for working on the system.

I have a 5 - 8 second delay on each page.

- I am running SqlServer 2000 Developer Edition on a Virtual Machine (Virtual PC).
- I have installed SqlServer on my development machine but get the same delay.
- I have isolated the issue to the call to mssql_connect (calling mssql_pconnect has no effect)
- It is a networking issue on how I have set up (or not set up, since I didn't really change default config) SQL server. It's not a strictly a programming issue but I thought I might get some valuable feedback here.

Can anyone tell me if there is a trick, specific set of protocols, registry setting, something that will kill this delay?

Comment: What is the host OS?  How are you referencing the DB server in the connection call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across network issues when running virtual pc, everything network related is slow, try adding this entry on your registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters

- Create new DWORD value named DisableTaskOffload and set its value to 1.
- Restart the computer.

It worked for me, [source](http://www.softblog.com/2009-12/slow-network-virtual-pc-windows-7/).

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: You could try to test out if anything else network related is slow, try transferring a file, if it goes slow then it's virtual pc related, for me, i migrated to virtualbox.

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing a 5-10 second delay on every connect, using the official Microsoft SQL drivers for PHP (as suggested by @gaRex) - none of the answers posted here solved it for me.

As suggested by @ircmaxell, my problem was a DNS issue - and the solution was to edit the `\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file (your local local host file) and add the name of my own machine to it.

In the "system properties" dialog, find the "computer name" of your machine - then add a line like `127.0.0.1 my-computer` to your local host file.

For me, the delay occurred once more, on the following attempt to load the page - after that, it was super fast, no delay at all.

Note that this problem may occur even on a physical machine, not only on a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Is it perhaps a DNS issue?  I know that MySQL does a reverse DNS lookup on each login (not each connection).  If you don't have a reverse dns record for your server (or your dns is slow) it can cause a major delay at login.  There's an option in MySQL to disable that.  I'm not sure about SQL Server, but I'd assume it may be doing something similar...

Answer (score 1):

I remember the same problem, but forgot, how we have solve it.

To clarify please specify exact connect strings, your SQLserver versions and also try to start this old good utility c:\WINDOWS\system32\cliconfg.exe, which is also can bring some light.

Yes, I know, it's from 2k, but guys at m$ don't like to create client tools from scratch.

Also try to get "right" mssql client dlls for PHP.